# Laravel hasMany Prerequisite from the same table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

In my `product` table for example i have this data

```
Laravel
Lumen
JavaScript
Eloquent
```

every this data maybe have prerequisite of **this table**, for example for `Lumen` user must be know `laravel` and for `Laravel` and `Lumen` user must be know `Eloquent`, how can i specify this prerequisite relationship on model?

i want to set one or many of this data on `form`, for example, for creating `Laravel` on table i can do select `Eloquent` or for `Eloquent` i can select `Laravel` and `Lumen` as an one prerequisite.

my `Products` model:

```
class Products extends Model
{
    use Sluggable;
    protected $table = 'products';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $casts = [
        'images' => 'array'
    ];

    public function productCategories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ProductCategories::class);
    }

    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Payment::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function sluggable()
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'main_title'
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
    }
}
```